# Confusion in "-ing" form verbs use

Tags: verbs, ing

I am a reading *Jane Eyre* book published by Oxford Bookworms.

I have found this sentence:

> [...], while I lay awake all night, trembling with fear, and eyes wide open in horror, imagining ghosts in every corner.

I do not know when to use "-ing" like trembling and imagining. There is no *be verb* before them and I cannot distinguish any relative clauses (I know be verbs can be omitted in some cases when there is relative clause.).

Would you please guide me a bit in this case?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things (which you probably want here), you can view the words "trembling" and "imagining" as simple adjectives in that context.

Not as the present continuous, which you probably meant.

So "trembling with fear" can simply by replaced with the adjective "scared".

If you want the non-simplified version, it is called present participle clause -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle :)

Participle clauses can be also thought of as shortened relative clauses, where you omit words like "who" and "which" and also the verb.

Comment: Thank you and which topic should I study to learn this type of simplifying?

Comment: Well, the topic to study is Participle. You can start by following the link  I provided in my answer. Also, if you think I helped you, please click the check icon below the vote arrows to Accept my answer. :)